# HttpRequestContext vs HttpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets, http, websocket

I have a question regarding `HttpRequestMessage` and `HttpContext`.

I am attempting to use web sockets in my project and have seen in a lot of examples to use the `HttpContext.IsWebSocketRequest` property and the `HttpContext.AcceptWebSocketRequest` method to check to see if the HTTP request that comes in is a web socket upgrade request or not ([Using WebSocket in .NET 4.5](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/618032/Using-WebSocket-in-NET-Part), and [Getting .NET 4.5 WebSockets Working](http://kasey-jo.blogspot.com/2012/09/getting-net-45-websockets-working.html)).

The issue I am having is that my controller than handles the HTTP GET request inherits from `ApiController` and the only thing that I seem to have access to when a request comes in is the `HttpRequestMessage.GetRequestContext()`. The `HttpContext.Current` where the web socket properties and methods I need live currently do exist in context it says.

My thought is that when the request comes in a new thread is spun up to handle the request, but I am unsure what to do. What can I do to get access to this `HttpContext.Current` object that I need so I can have web socket functionality?

So to sum up, what I want to achieve is something along the lines of:

```
if(HttpContext.Current.IsWebSocketRequest() == true){
    Console.WriteLine("Yay!");
}
```

But I get a HttpContext does not exist in the current context error.